# What is the order of evaluation when chaining multiple TermFilters(TermQuery) in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the order of evaluation of the TermsFilter (or the newer TermsQuery) when multiple TermsFilter are chained together?

```
for eg.     should { termsquery1, termsquery2}
```

And what is the order of evaluation in the event that the above TermsFilter(TermsQuery) is nested within another Filter?

```
for eg.    must{ termsquery3, should{ termsquery1,termsquery2}}
```

I would like to know if the order in which the terms are specified will matter with regards to query performance?

Specifically having termsquery3 as a filter, will it speed up evaluation of termsquery1 & termsquery2 owing to the fact termsquery1 & termsquery2 will operate on a smaller subset of the corpus.

In my use case.

```
Termsquery1 -> Large set of terms
Termsquery3 -> smaller set of terms 
and TermsQuery1 >> TermsQuery2 (greatly exceeeds)
TermsQuery3 & TermsQuery2 are comparable with the number of terms.
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a response from the Elastic discussion forum for the above question

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-is-the-order-of-evaluation-of-the-termsfilter-or-the-newer-termsquery-when-multiple-termsfilter-are-chained-together/36704